# Putting a button between and over two buttons linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a small fun project where I am building an one octave piano. I am trying to figure out how to add the black keys between and over the white keys. I am thinking I need to use a nested layout (maybe RelativeLayout) inside my horizontal LinearLayout.It should look something similar to the pic below.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="66"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftRail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/f_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/g_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/a_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightRail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` does not allow overlapping children. You'd need to use a `ViewGroup` that does; e.g., `ConstraintLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc. Though, for something like this, I'd actually recommend writing a custom `View` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you build your layout using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

As it provides you fully responsive UI. And manage the view as per your requirement very easy.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunny has already suggested use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) as it allows for a ton of things. And also instead of using fixed heights and weights you can use proportions and guidelines to make buttons the same shape no matter the screen.

Added benefit if you place those 12 buttons in their own separate layout as you can later use it to build a whole keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is **not the good and correct approach** for archive this. But using `Framelayout` and `Linearlayout` we can archive this like follows.

`Layout.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/leftRail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/c_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/d_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/f_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/g_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/a_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/rightRail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/black_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/black_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/black_3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/black_4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/black_5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_weight="1.5" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Output
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a nested layout, you can use  [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)  to achive this.

It's very easy to put one view over another view using constraintlayout, you may want to do **something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This layout will be responsive to all devices and look like this:**

[image]

**This will work both in portrait and landscape mode:**

[image]

---

### Extra reading

- Do you want to change the height and width of everything and keep your layout responsive? just change those 2 attributes on your views:

  ```
  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent
  app:layout_constraintWidth_percent
  ```
- If you want to know Why is this responsive:

I am not using a fixed size values on my views, I am telling my views to take `xx%` of the screen height and width and by doing that my layout remains responsive.

---

### If you are telling yourself "this new layout looks hard..."

At first, it may look hard to handle but you may want to give it a try because constraitnLayout is:

- constraitnLayout is really user-friendly when building your UI with it.
- ConstraintLayout is very easy and simple to learn, it got good documentation and tutorials (like a lot of them).
- once you have learned it you will see that you are saving **a lot of development time** because making your UI is simply fast.
- Constraint layout is meant to support different screen sizes so no need to build a layout for every screen size (this also connect to the previous advantage- saving development time).